# Why do my google cloud compute instances always unexpectedly restart?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Help! Help! Help!

It is really annoying and I almost cannot bear it anymore! I'm using google cloud compute engine instances but they often unexpectedly restart without any notification in advance. The restart of instances seems to happen randomly and I have no idea what's going wrong there! I'm pretty sure that the instances are been occupied (usage of CPUs > 50% and all GPUs are in use) when restart happens. Could anyone please tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19):

The issue is right here:

> all GPUs are in use

If you check the official  [documentation about GPU](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#restrictions):

> GPU instances must terminate for host maintenance events, but can automatically restart. These maintenance events typically occur once per week, but can occur more frequently when necessary. You must configure your workloads to handle these maintenance events cleanly. Specifically, long-running workloads like machine learning and high-performance computing (HPC) must handle the interruption of host maintenance events. [Learn how to handle host maintenance events on instances with GPUs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#host-maintenance).

This is because an instance that has a GPU attached cannot be migrated to another host for maintenance as it happens for the rest of the virtual machines. To get a physical GPU attached to the instance and bare metal performance you are using GPU passthrough , which sadly means if the host has to go through maintenance the VM is going down with it.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like [Preemptible VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible).

Preemptible instances function like normal instances, but have the following limitations:

- Compute Engine might terminate preemptible instances at any time due to system events. The probability that Compute Engine will terminate a preemptible instance for a system event is generally low, but might vary from day to day and from zone to zone depending on current conditions.
- Compute Engine always terminates preemptible instances after they run for 24 hours.

To check if your instance is preemptible using gcloud cli, just run

```
gcloud compute instances describe instance-name --format="(scheduling.preemptible)"
```

Result

```
scheduling:
  preemptible: false
```

change "instance-name" to real name.

Or simply via UI, click on compute instance and scroll down:
[image]

To check for system operations performed on your instance, you can review it using following command:

```
gcloud compute operations list
```

Comment: Ahh.. I even didn't know preemptible instances before this. But some of my instances could run continuously for more than 24 hours, or days. So assumed that my instances are not premptible, do you have other suggestions to solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @ROBOTAI : don't blindly make any assumptions and check scheduling settings in console or CLI...

Comment: Hi @rkosegi, thanks for your detailed tutorial! I have checked and found both the Preemptibility and Automatic restart are on the same options as yours. But my third one: On host maintenance is "Terminate VM instance". Could this be where the problem lays?

Comment: @ROBOTAI : yes, according to offical doc, it will terminate your VM and restart it. Did you read about [scheduling policies](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options)? Any reason why you have non-recommended settings as such?

Comment: If you're using GPUs on your instances, it's an inherent limitation that they cannot live migrate on host maintenance events; they get restarted instead. Read this: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#restrictions

Comment: @asamarin is right. The official document said that's a constraint for GPU instances. So the only thing I can do is to frequently check the status of my running programs.