# Why are my compute engine instances getting restarted?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm running a cloud load balancer to dispatch incoming requests to two CPE instances.

It runs fine on some days, on others the instances are getting restarted for no obvious reason so all processes (mainly tomcat) are getting terminated and users are receiving errors.

I'm not running Preemptible VM instances (I've check according to [Why do my google cloud compute instances always unexpectedly restart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475029/why-do-my-google-cloud-compute-instances-always-unexpectedly-restart) )

How can I find out why the instances are getting restarted? The experience is getting more and more frustrating.
I used to run a cluster of cheap hosted servers for years before switching to GCP and never had any issues - and it was much (much) cheaper.
I thought I would get better performance and better scalability, but if the whole setup is not realiable, it does not make much sense.

How do I get any info WHY the instances are getting restarted. I do not find anything in my logs (neither in load balancer, nor in the compute engine logs).

Comment: How do you know the instances are being restarted?  Are you running windows or linux on the instances?  If linux, are there bootlogs that tell us when the instances is being restarted?   Might it be an autoscaling story where the load becomes so low that the autoscaler decides to lower the number of instances to zero?

Comment: I'm running Linux on the instances. I have watched them getting restarted right in the cloud console instances page (and of course from the users emails complaining about service interruption).
They've been restarted multiple times (about 20 times or so), but only on a specific day and without any notice in the logs. Sometimes they are running without any issues for many days, but then again lots of restarts.No idea how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the instance are failing because of the health check or any other issue like (Live migrate, Terminate and Automatic restart event). That being said, I would recommend checking your [stackdriver logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) for the particular instance to see why the instances are getting restarted. Also at the same time also I would recommend you to check [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options) which will help you to understand and see logs for Live migrate, Terminate and Automatic restart this type of event.

Comment: I guess I would see something in the logs of the load balancer then?

Comment: Once you go to Stack driver logs and then you can specify the affected instance name to see the logs for that specific instance and also you can mentioned the time frame as well. Additionally you can also use this advance filter by using this article (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters#getting_started_with_advanced_filters)

Comment: In the instance log I found interesting info:
  info: [
   0: {
    code:  "STATUS_MESSAGE"     
    detail_message:  "Instance Group Manager 'projects/204806608852/zones/us-central1-f/instanceGroupManagers/ultradox-libreoffice' initiated recreateInstance on instance 'projects/204806608852/zones/us-central1-f/instances/ultradox-libreoffice-lsjb'. Reason: instance's current action is NONE, but health status is UNHEALTHY."



But I cannot see anything in the logs of the health check?

Comment: I will suggest that the health check should not be too aggressive so as to allow for the Instance group rebuild the unhealthy [Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#monitoring_groups). See the “Note: Use separate health checks for load balancing and for autohealing.”

Comment: Logs will help you to track what is going in the instance. You could setup Stackdriver at Instance level so that you could have a log of what might be restarting the [instance](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/) or any other logging tool that will help you retrieve logs after instance is deleted.