# How to prevent GCP compute instances from resetting by itself?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, tensorflow2.0

I'm training a RL agent (more precisely, a stable baselines agent written using Tensorflow) on a GCP VM instance.
The agent runs fine if I train for a small number of steps (e.g. 100k time steps). However, if I set the training steps to be large (e.g. 5 million), the instance always gets reset by itself after ~1 day of training. The error message reads:

> ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

What can I do to prevent the connection being reset by peer?

p.s. I'm using the default setting of the VM instance.

Instance Machine type:

> c2-standard-4 (4 vCPUs, 16 GB memory)

Update1:
Since I suspect this may be related to preemptible VM instance, I ran `gcloud compute operations list` and I got a a few lines saying:

> compute.instances.migrateOnHostMaintenance

However the preemptibility is off in `availability policies`:

> Preemptibility    Off (recommended)
> On host maintenance   Migrate VM instance (recommended)
> Automatic restart On (recommended)

And according to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/setting-instance-scheduling-options#live_migrate, the instance should not be stopped during live migration...

Update2:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "run_baselines_agent.py", line 28, in _train
> envs = SubprocVecEnv([make_env(env_id) for _ in range(NUM_CPU)])
> File "/home/sg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/stable_baselines/common/vec_env/subproc_vec_env.py", line 99, in **init**
> observation_space, action_space = self.remotes[0].recv()
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
> buf = self._recv_bytes()
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
> buf = self._recv(4)
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
> chunk = read(handle, remaining)
> ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Comment: If you're using GPU or preemptible, then it's a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475029/why-do-my-google-cloud-compute-instances-always-unexpectedly-restart

Comment: Thanks for digging that up! My instance doesn't use GPU (see my updated machine type) but the "Preemptible VM instance" section does seem to be related.

Comment: Some updates: After some research, both preemptibility and live migration don't seem to be the real cause.

Comment: could you share a snippet from your code and the complete error tracefor have a better context ?

Comment: Hey, I updated the question with the traceback. https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines is the stable-baselines package mentioned in the trace.